# Running a select statement for each case

Tags: sql

I'm a complete SQL novice. I want to display a simple grid.....

1. **Sign up......>30.....30-60.....60-90.....>90.....Total**
2. **Feb**...............4..........30...........      6      ......... 0     .......40
3. **Mar**   ............. 0 .........11      ...........1       ..........4     .......16
4. **Apr**
5. **May**          etc
6. **Jun**                         etc

Where **total** represents the total of number of customer sign ups per month, and where the likes of '30-60' represents the number sign ups on the date 30-60 days since today's date

The query I am using is as follows......

```
SELECT case MONTH(Datecreated)
when   2 then 'Febrary'
when   3 then 'March'
when   4 then 'April'
when   5 then 'May'
when   6 then 'June'
end as 'Signup Month',


(select count(*) from WS_USER_DETAILS where datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 30 )  as  '<= 30 days',
(select count(*) from WS_USER_DETAILS where datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) between 30 and 60) as  '<= 60 days',
(select count(*) from WS_USER_DETAILS where datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) between 60 and 90) as  '<= 90 days',
(select count(*) from WS_USER_DETAILS where datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) >90) as  '<= 120 days', 

count(userid) AS 'Total' FROM WS_USER_DETAILS


group by MONTH(Datecreated)
```

The problem I have is....
I want to run the select statements for each month. However it populates all months. For example......

1. **Sign up......>30.....30-60.....60-90.....>90.....Total**
2. **Feb**...............0..........11...........      1      ......... 4     .......40
3. **Mar**   ............. 0 .........11      ...........1       ..........4     .......16

If possible can someone advise me on how to run the select statements for each month? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the time span per record, then group and count. Be careful not to have overlapping ranges.

```
select
  monthname,
  isnull(sum(lessthan30),0) as lt30,
  isnull(sum(between30and59),0) as btw30a59,
  isnull(sum(between60and89),0) as btw60a89,
  isnull(sum(between90and119),0) as btw90a119,
  isnull(sum(morethan119),0) as mt119,
  isnull(sum(lessthan30),0) + isnull(sum(between30and59),0) + isnull(sum(between60and89),0) + isnull(sum(between90and119),0) + isnull(sum(morethan119),0) as total
from
(
  select
    month(datecreated) as mon,
    datename(month,datecreated) as monthname,
    case when datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 30 then 1 else 0 end as lessthan30,
    case when datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) between 30 and 59 then 1 else 0 end as between30and59,
    case when datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) between 60 and 89 then 1 else 0 end as between60and89,
    case when datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) between 90 and 119 then 1 else 0 end as between90and119,
    case when datediff(day, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) >= 120 then 1 else 0 end as morethan119
  from WS_USER_DETAILS
) as dummy
group by monthname, mon
order by mon;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. When I run this I get ' Incorrect syntax near ')'.'

Comment: Ah, sorry, in SQL Server each derived table must have a name. (Plus there was an empty WHERE clause - don't know how it got there :-) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for update. However I now get Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'month'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'month'.

Comment: Yes, a typo. The month we select in the inner select (the derived table) is called mon not month. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would fit your needs better. You can use Sum Function and a case statement to work like a count if.

```
    SELECT
    DATENAME(MM,Datecreated), --This Function automatically gets the name of the month

    --Here is where you can use case statements like a count if. 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '<= 30 days',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '<= 60 days',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '<= 90 days',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, datecreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '<= 120 days'

    FROM WS_USER_DETAILS

    GROUP BY Datepart(MM, Datecreated)
```

### Sources:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: Thanks the response. I get an error.... 'Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'WS_USER_DETAILS.dateCreated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause......

Comment: Do you have the Group by statement in the query?:
GROUP BY Datepart(MM, Datecreated)

Comment: Yep. Group By is in the query

Comment: I used   GROUP BY dateCreated and this worked. Thanks

Comment: This is looking much better for me. However I would like to display  1 row per month, i.e. count the number of occurrences

Answer (score 1):

Based on @ThorstenKettner but adding performance by removing function calls and adding [sergability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

```
declare @today date
declare @_30 date
declare @_31 date
declare @_59 date
declare @_60 date
declare @_89 date
declare @_90 date
declare @_119 date
declare @_120 date


set @today = GETUTCDATE()
set @_30 = datediff(day, @today, 30)
set @_31 = datediff(day, @today, 31)
set @_59 = datediff(day, @today, 59)
set @_60 = datediff(day, @today, 60)
set @_89 = datediff(day, @today, 89)
set @_90 = datediff(day, @today, 90)
set @_119 = datediff(day, @today, 119)
set @_120 = datediff(day, @today, 120)


select
  monthname,
  isnull(sum(lessthan30),0) as lt30,
  isnull(sum(between30and59),0) as btw30a59,
  isnull(sum(between60and89),0) as btw60a89,
  isnull(sum(between90and119),0) as btw90a119,
  isnull(sum(morethan119),0) as mt119,
  isnull(sum(lessthan30),0) + isnull(sum(between30and59),0) + isnull(sum(between60and89),0) + isnull(sum(between90and119),0) + isnull(sum(morethan119),0) as total
from
(
  select
    month(datecreated) as mon,
    datename(month,datecreated) as monthname,
    case when datecreated < @_30 then 1 else 0 end as lessthan30,
    case when datecreated between @_30 and @_59 then 1 else 0 end as between30and59,
    case when datecreated  between @_60 and @_89 then 1 else 0 end as between60and89,
    case when datecreated  between @_90 and @_119 then 1 else 0 end as between90and119,
    case when datecreated  >= @_120 then 1 else 0 end as morethan119
  from WS_USER_DETAILS 
)as dummy
group by monthname, mon
order by mon;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I get an issue with the group by ........... Expecting AS, ID, or Quoted ID

Comment: I' just replicated the changes from previous answer. Check it. And make sure you have an index on `datecreated` for optimal performance